# Matrix multiplication of non-commuting objects

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have two matrices, $A$ and $B$. The elements of these matrices are some abstract non-commuting objects, which I'm just representing as variables. For now, I don't care about having Mathematica know about the specifics of these commutation relations - all I care about is that it doesn't assume that they commute, so that, for example, when I calculate something like $\text{Tr}(A B)$, the expression that it returns keeps the elements of $A$ in front of the elements of $B$. Of course for something as simple as $\text{Tr}(AB)$ I can just rearrange the elements by hand, but I would like to have the ability to do this for more complex expressions, with potentially more than two matrices. It seems Mathematica has some built-in functionality for non-commutative multiplication, but this is only for scalars - is there something that generalizes this to matrices of non-commuting objects?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As `Dot` is a special case of [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html) with `Dot[##] == Inner[Times,##, Plus]`, we can just tell *Mathematica* to use [`NonCommutativeMultiply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonCommutativeMultiply.html) in the first slot to take the place of regular multiplication.

```
ncdot[ten1_, ten2_] := Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, ten1, ten2, Plus]
ncdot[{x, y}, {u, v}]
ncdot[{{x, y}, {z, w}}, {{a, b}, {c, d}}]
Tr@%
```

> x ** u + y ** v

> {{x ** a + y ** c, x ** b + y ** d}, {w ** c + z ** a,
> w ** d + z ** b}}

> w ** d + x ** a + y ** c + z ** b

This contrasts the automatic canonical sorting MMA does under the hood of the individual symbols as in

```
{x, y}.{u, v}
(*and*)
{{x, y}, {z, w}}.{{a, b}, {c, d}} // Tr
```

> u x + v y

> d w + a x + c y + b z

To use this for **several items** (e.g. matrices $A,B,C$), we incorporate/redefine [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) into the definition as

```
ncdot[tens__] := Fold[Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, ##] &, {tens}]
(*Without the inclusion of the fourth argument of Inner, the default is Plus*)
```

Which we can use as

```
ncdot @@ Table[i[j, k], {i, {a, b, c}}, {j, 2}, {k, 2}];
% /. (i : (a | b | c))[j_, k_] :> Subscript[i, j\[InvisibleComma]k] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cc} \left(a_{1,1}\text{**}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}\text{**}b_{2,1}\right)\text{**}c_{1,1}+\left(a_{1,1}\text{**}b_{
   1,2}+a_{1,2}\text{**}b_{2,2}\right)\text{**}c_{2,1} &
\left(a_{1,1}\text{**}b_{1,1}+a_{1,2}\text{**}b_{2,1}\right)\text{**}c_{1,2}+\left(a_{1,1}\text{**}b_{
   1,2}+a_{1,2}\text{**}b_{2,2}\right)\text{**}c_{2,2} \\
\left(a_{2,1}\text{**}b_{1,1}+a_{2,2}\text{**}b_{2,1}\right)\text{**}c_{1,1}+\left(a_{2,1}\text{**}b_{
   1,2}+a_{2,2}\text{**}b_{2,2}\right)\text{**}c_{2,1} &
\left(a_{2,1}\text{**}b_{1,1}+a_{2,2}\text{**}b_{2,1}\right)\text{**}c_{1,2}+\left(a_{2,1}\text{**}b_{
   1,2}+a_{2,2}\text{**}b_{2,2}\right)\text{**}c_{2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
Tr[{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{{x, y}, {z, w}}] /. Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply
Tr[{{a, b}, {c, d}}.{{x, y}, {z, w}} /. Times -> NonCommutativeMultiply]
```

> `a ** x + b ** z + c ** y + d ** w`