# NonCommutativeMultiply in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrix, tensors

Is there a way to preserve the order of elements in the multiplication of matrices when the elements themselves are matrices?

For example, if I have:

```
Matrix1 = {{Amat[x],Bmat[x]},{Cmat[x],Dmat[x]}};
Matrix2 = {{Amat[y],Bmat[y]},{Cmat[y],Dmat[y]}};
```

Where each of the `Amat`,`Bmat`,`Cmat`, and `Dmat` are all matrices dependent upon some input `x` or `y`. I can form the matrices:

```
Matrix3 = KroneckerProduct[Matrix1,IdentityMatrix[2]];
Matrix4 = KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[2],Matrix2];
```

And I can take their product:

```
Matrix3.Matrix4
```

which outputs:

```
{{Amat[x] Amat[y], Amat[x] Bmat[y], Amat[y] Bmat[x], Bmat[x] Bmat[y]},
 {Amat[x] Cmat[y], Amat[x] Dmat[y], Bmat[x] Cmat[y], Bmat[x] Dmat[y]},
 {Amat[y] Cmat[x], Bmat[y] Cmat[x], Amat[y] Dmat[x], Bmat[y] Dmat[x]},
 {Cmat[x] Cmat[y], Cmat[x] Dmat[y], Cmat[y] Dmat[x], Dmat[x] Dmat[y]}}
```

But we see that the entry in the first row of the third column is `Amat[y]Bmat[x]` when it should be `Bmat[x]Amat[y]` due to the non-commutative matrix multiplication.

The answers in [Matrix multiplication of non-commuting objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/236029/51196) and [Matrix multiplication in Block Form symbolic calculation by Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/matrix-multiplication-in-block-form-symbolic-calculation-by-mathematica) I believe give me what I want, but I also expected a `FullSimplify` to simplify `0`'s:

For example, using the first solution from [Matrix multiplication of non-commuting objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/236029/51196), defining

```
ncdot[ten1_, ten2_] := Inner[NonCommutativeMultiply, ten1, ten2, Plus]
```

and applying this (and `FullSimplify`) to `Matrix3` and `Marix4` we have:

```
FullSimplify[ncdot[Matrix3,Matrix4]] = {{0 ** 0 + 0 ** Cmat[y] + Amat[x] ** Amat[y] + Bmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Dmat[y] + Amat[x] ** Bmat[y] + Bmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Cmat[y] + Amat[x] ** 0 + Bmat[x] ** Amat[y], 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Dmat[y] + Amat[x] ** 0 + 
   Bmat[x] ** Bmat[y]}, {0 ** 0 + 0 ** Amat[y] + Amat[x] ** Cmat[y] + 
   Bmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Bmat[y] + Amat[x] ** Dmat[y] + Bmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Amat[y] + Amat[x] ** 0 + Bmat[x] ** Cmat[y], 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Bmat[y] + Amat[x] ** 0 + 
   Bmat[x] ** Dmat[y]}, {0 ** 0 + 0 ** Cmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** Amat[y] + 
   Dmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Dmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** Bmat[y] + Dmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Cmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** 0 + Dmat[x] ** Amat[y], 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Dmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** 0 + 
   Dmat[x] ** Bmat[y]}, {0 ** 0 + 0 ** Amat[y] + Cmat[x] ** Cmat[y] + 
   Dmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Bmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** Dmat[y] + Dmat[x] ** 0, 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Amat[y] + Cmat[x] ** 0 + Dmat[x] ** Cmat[y], 
  0 ** 0 + 0 ** Bmat[y] + Cmat[x] ** 0 + Dmat[x] ** Dmat[y]}}
```

And similarly, from [Matrix multiplication in Block Form symbolic calculation by Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7902/matrix-multiplication-in-block-form-symbolic-calculation-by-mathematica), defining:

```
blockMultiply[mats__] := Inner[Dot, mats];
```

and applying this (and `FullSimplify`) to `Matrix3` and `Matrix4`, we see:

```
FullSimplify[blockMultiply[Matrix3, Matrix4]]={{0 . 0 + 0 . Cmat[y] + Amat[x] . Amat[y] + Bmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Dmat[y] + Amat[x] . Bmat[y] + Bmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Cmat[y] + Amat[x] . 0 + Bmat[x] . Amat[y], 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Dmat[y] + Amat[x] . 0 + Bmat[x] . Bmat[y]}, {0 . 0 + 
   0 . Amat[y] + Amat[x] . Cmat[y] + Bmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Bmat[y] + Amat[x] . Dmat[y] + Bmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Amat[y] + Amat[x] . 0 + Bmat[x] . Cmat[y], 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Bmat[y] + Amat[x] . 0 + Bmat[x] . Dmat[y]}, {0 . 0 + 
   0 . Cmat[y] + Cmat[x] . Amat[y] + Dmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Dmat[y] + Cmat[x] . Bmat[y] + Dmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Cmat[y] + Cmat[x] . 0 + Dmat[x] . Amat[y], 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Dmat[y] + Cmat[x] . 0 + Dmat[x] . Bmat[y]}, {0 . 0 + 
   0 . Amat[y] + Cmat[x] . Cmat[y] + Dmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Bmat[y] + Cmat[x] . Dmat[y] + Dmat[x] . 0, 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Amat[y] + Cmat[x] . 0 + Dmat[x] . Cmat[y], 
  0 . 0 + 0 . Bmat[y] + Cmat[x] . 0 + Dmat[x] . Dmat[y]}}
```

Is there a way to preserve the order? Perhaps somehow using `NonCommutativeMultiply`, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add a definition to "Dot" for a zero term and use "Inner".

The addition to "Dot":

```
Unprotect[Dot];
0 . _ = 0; _ . 0 = 0;
Protect[Dot];
```

Now we can write the searched for multiplication:

```
Inner[Dot, Matrix3, Matrix4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: This worked! But is there a way to make scalar multiplication commute to the front? For example, if I take Inner[Dot,a*Matrix3,b*Matrix4]//MatrixForm, the scalars don't commute to the front.

Comment: The problem with this that MMA expands e.g.: `a Matrix1` to `{{a Amat[x], a Bmat[x]}, {a Cmat[x], a Dmat[x]}}`automatically.